# Quicker, Pandas-friendly way to complete this algorithm?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a very large DataFrame where each element is populate with a 1-5 integer, or else 0 if there is no data for that element. I would like to create two adjusted copies of it:

- `train` will be a copy where a random 20% of non-zero elements per row are set to 0
- `test` will be a copy where all but these same 20% of elements are set to 0

Here is a sample:

```
ORIGINAL
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  3  0  1  1  3  5  3  5  4  2
1  4  2  3  2  3  3  4  4  1  2
2  2  4  2  5  4  4  0  0  4  2

TRAIN
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  3  0  0  1  3  5  3  5  4  2
1  4  2  3  0  3  3  4  4  0  2
2  2  4  2  5  4  4  0  0  4  0

TEST
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2
```

Here is my current brute-force algorithm that gets the job done, but is far too slow:

```
train, test = original.copy(), original.copy()
for i in range(original.shape[0]):
    print("{} / {}".format(i + 1, original.shape[0]))
    row = original.iloc[i]                      # Select row
    nonZeroIndices = np.where(row > 0)[0]       # Find all non-zero indices
    numTest = int(len(nonZeroIndices) * 0.2)    # Calculate 20% of this amount
    rand = np.random.choice(nonZeroIndices, numTest, replace=False)  # Select a rancom 20% of non-zero indices

    for j in range(original.shape[1]):
        if j in rand:
            train.iloc[i, j] = 0
        else:
            test.iloc[i, j] = 0
```

Is there a quicker way to achieve this using Pandas or Numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the 20% subset of non-zero values with `sample()`:

```
subset = df.apply(lambda x: x[x.ne(0)].sample(frac=.2, random_state=42), axis=1)

subset
     1    2    5    8
0  NaN  1.0  NaN  4.0
1  2.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
2  4.0  NaN  4.0  NaN
```

Now `train` and `test` can be set by multiplying `subset` against the original `df`, and either using 1s or 0s as `fill_value`:

```
train = df.apply(lambda x: x.multiply(subset.iloc[x.name].isnull(), fill_value=1), axis=1)

train
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  3  0  0  1  3  5  3  5  0  2
1  4  0  3  2  3  3  4  4  0  2
2  2  0  2  5  4  0  0  0  4  2

test = df.apply(lambda x: x.multiply(subset.iloc[x.name].notnull(), fill_value=0), axis=1)

test
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  4  0
1  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  4  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0
```

Data:

```
df
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  3  0  1  1  3  5  3  5  4  2
1  4  2  3  2  3  3  4  4  1  2
2  2  4  2  5  4  4  0  0  4  2
```

Comment: Very elegant, thank you. Lastly, is `random_state` in `df.sample` just for reproducibility? I don't actually need it?

Comment: You're welcome.  And that's correct, setting `random_state` here is just for reproducibility, you don't need it.

Comment: This actually seems to be a good deal slower than the original solution on the given test data set (cf. the timings in the answer below).

Comment: It is actually impressively quick compared to my solution on a large DataFrame (seconds vs minutes)

Comment: It's true that Pandas will often run slower than some of the Numpy methods it's overlaying.  And using `apply` is basically a glorified for-loop, there aren't huge vectorized gains to be made there.  I'd guess there's probably a good way to draw the entire `subset` at once, rather than calling `sample()` on each row, as `apply()` does here.  Edits welcome!

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be

```
def make_train_test(df):
    train, test = df.copy(), df.copy()
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        non_zero = np.where(row > 0)[0]
        num_test = int(len(non_zero) * 0.2)
        rand = np.random.choice(non_zero, num_test, replace=False)
        row_train = train.iloc[i, :]
        row_test = test.iloc[i, :]
        row_train[rand] = 0
        row_test[~row_test.index.isin(rand)] = 0
    return train, test
```

In my testing, this runs in about 4.85 ms, your original solution in about 9.07 ms, and andrew_reece's (otherwise elegant) solution in 15.6 ms.

Comment: I appreciate that you approach may be faster, but a goal of mine is to improve my skills with Pandas, and the question specifically asked for a more Pandas-friendly solution, so I am keeping andrew_reece's as the accepted answer. Upvoted for efficiency though.

Comment: Nice efficiency @fuglede!